# I am trying to filter array within another

Tags: typescript, angular6

I am trying to filter array within another that is symptoms in this sceneario.

My data & code is as follows:

```
illnesses = [

      {"cause": "abc", "symptoms": ["A", "B", "C"]},   
      {"cause": "def", "symptoms": ["g", "s", "k", "j"]}  
]


filterCauses(searchString: string){
    return this.illnesses.filter(
      (c) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.cause.length; i++) {
          c.symptoms.filter( d => d.symptoms[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
        }
      }
    )
}
```

Comment: What is an expected input and output?

Comment: Expected input can be anything from the symptoms values and I will have to return the value if it exists in symptoms array.

Comment: could you show you expected output?

Comment: I need to return the certain entry of a symptom array like if the input is A then it should filter and return A from the symptoms array as an output instead of returning all the entries

Answer (score 0):

```js
filterCauses(searchString: string){
  return this.illnesses.filter(illness => illness.symptoms.includes(searchString))
}
```

Comment: It doesn't get any value.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `some` method, which tells you if any of the array's items fit a predicate:

If you want the entire arrays of any `cause` that contains a symptom with the passed in searchString, you could do:

```js
filterCauses(searchString: string) {
  searchString = searchString.toUpperCase();
  return this.illnesses.filter((i) => i.symptoms.some((s) => s.toUpperCase()
      .includes(searchString)));
}
```

#### UPDATE 1:

If you just want the possible causes:

```js
filterCauses(searchString: string): string[] {
  searchString = searchString.toUpperCase();
  return this.illnesses.filter((i) => i.symptoms.some((s) => s.toUpperCase()
      .includes(searchString))).map((i) => i.cause);
}
```

#### UPDATE 2: (asked in comments)

If you just want the possible symptoms:

```js
filterCauses(searchString: string): string[] {
  searchString = searchString.toUpperCase();
  const symptomSet: Set<string> = new Set<string>();
  this.illnesses.forEach((i) => {
    i.symptoms.forEach((s) => {
      if(s.toUpperCase().includes(searchString)) {
        symptomSet.add(s);
      }
    }
  }

  return Array.from(symptomSet.values());
}
```

#### UPDATE 3: (asked in comments)

```js
// @return comma separated list of matching symptoms
filterCauses(searchString: string): string {
  searchString = searchString.toUpperCase();
  const symptomSet: Set<string> = new Set<string>();
  this.illnesses.forEach((i) => {
    i.symptoms.forEach((s) => {
      if(s.toUpperCase().includes(searchString)) {
        symptomSet.add(s);
      }
    }
  }

  return Array.from(symptomSet.values())
           .reduce((acc:string,a:string) => acc += (acc ? ', ' : '') + a,'');
}
```

Comment: It shows every entry of specific arrays like if the data is {"cause": "abc", "symptoms": ["A", "B", "C"]},then it will show A,B,C

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following you... given a text (part of the name o a symptom), what you want? The entire array that has that symptom, or just the cause?

Comment: What I want is to return the certain entry of a symptom array like if the input is A then it should filter and return A from the symptoms array as an output instead of returning all the entries.

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working I believe so but I will have to display it in html template so and what I were using to display was {{somevar.symptoms}}, but since it is an array so how can I display it there?

Comment: Thank you so much :). It is working and html template is fine too.